# BingService doesn't accept requests for Hybrid and Other Bing Map formats

Tags: java, geotools, bing-maps

We have used `BingService` with the help of following code:

```
String baseURL = "http://ak.dynamic.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/${code}?mkt=de-de&it=G,VE,BX,L,LA&shading=hill&og=78&n=z"`;

map.layers().add(0, (new TileLayer(new BingService("Hybrid", baseURL))));
```

but `BingService` always create a Road map.

Is there any way to create `Hybrid` and `Arial` map?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Javadoc of the `BingService` class it points you to the [Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701716.aspx) that gives details of how to generate URLs to access the service.